# Generics: TS2345 Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date' where <T extends {}>

Tags: typescript, generics, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, ecmascript-5

I often have to sort objects by properties, so I wrote the following simple helper:

```
static sort = <T extends {}>(list: Array<T>, field: keyof T, descending: boolean = true) =>
  list.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[field] > b[field]) {
      return descending ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return descending ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

I often have to sort objects by a date-like property on the object, but the dates I receive are stringified in the format `"01-Apr-2018"`, so I have to convert them into a Date first.

So, I expanded the above with:

```
static byDate = <T extends {}>(list: Array<T>, field: keyof T, descending: boolean = true) =>
  list.sort((a, b) => {
    if (new Date(a[field]).getTime() > new Date(b[field]).getTime()) {
      return descending ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
      return descending ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

which results in

> TS2345: Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

on `a[field]` and `b[field]`.

Tracing WebStorm's / TypeScript Service's implementation of Date that was chosen, I noticed that in `new Date("hello")`, it chooses the following interface from `lib.es5.d.ts`:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    new(value: number): Date;
    new(value: string): Date; // THIS ONE (which I expect)
    new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    (): string;
    readonly prototype: Date;
    parse(s: string): number;
    UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): number;
    now(): number;
}
```

But in my sort comparator, it chooses [the interface from `lib.es2015.core.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.2/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L92), which only has:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new (value: Date): Date;
}
```

Attempting to assert with `new Date(a[field] as string)` or `as Date` has no effect.

I'm using TypeScript 2.7.2 (required by my current Angular 6.0.9 project and can't change).

So:

1. Why does `tsc` choose one over the other in these contexts?
2. How can I assert which one I want it to use, or at the very least, get my code to compile while maintaining the `field: keyof T` parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't test on 2.7.2 right now, but the main issue is that TypeScript doesn't believe that `a[field]` is necessarily a `string`.  And that makes sense because `a` is of generic type `T`, and `field` is of type `keyof T`, so all it knows is that `a[field]` is `T[keyof T]`.  That *might* be `string`, or it might be something that you can't call `new Date()` on.

If you know for sure that you will only call `byDate` on something where `a[field]` is a `string`, then you can change the generics to be like this:

```
static byDate = <K extends keyof any, T extends Record<K, string>>(
  list: Array<T>, 
  field: K, 
  descending: boolean = true
) => { ... }
```

That should make the error go away... it now knows that `a[field]` is type `T[K]`, where `T` extends `Record<K, string>`, also known as `{[P in K]: string}`, or "an object whose keys are in `K` and whose values are `string`".  So `T[K]` extends `string` and it's happy.

The above *should* work on TypeScript 2.7.2 but let me know if you run into a problem.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: It does indeed! That was exactly the generic I was looking for. Many thanks for the additional explanation.